# Code Snippet creation is not available in lightning menu

Tags: mac, desktop, slack

In **slack** desktop app for mac (version 4.11.2 3768d69-s@1605843152), I can't find the way to create code snippet with syntax highlighting.

It used to be accessible from lightning menu from message box, as shown in slack documentation (cf picture below), but it seems it's not there anymore.

Would anyone know how to create code snippet nowadays ?

Thanks

[image: lightning menu capture from slack documentation]

https://slack.com/intl/en-ca/slack-tips/share-code-snippets

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is simple, but still I had to make a few try to find it.

As I'm using slack in french the code snippet functionality just couldn't be found using the keywords "*code*", "*snippet*" or "*create*". Instead I should have looked for the command "*Créer un extrait de texte*". The word "*code*" in that last command name would have been helpful.

Hope that will help someone someday.

[image]